# Is there a way to upgrade an azure app service plan using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

Trying to use the powershell command Set-AzAppServicePlan to upgrade a App Service Plan from Standard S1 plan to a Standard S3 plan.  There doesn't seem to be a way to define the "S3".

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier "Standard"  -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Small";
```

I've tried all manner of different values in the "-Tier" param such as "StandardS3" or "StandardV3" and it always defaults to "Standard S1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are looking for **`WorkerSize`**

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier "Standard"  -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Small"
```

`workerSize` options are small, medium, large, extralarge

Answer (score 8):

Here is less confusing way

```
# Set the App Service Plan name and resource group name
$appServicePlanName = "YourAppServicePlanName"
$resourceGroupName = "YourResourceGroupName"

# Set the SKU name to P0v3
$sku = "P0v3"

# Get the App Service Plan
$appServicePlan = Get-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName

# Set the SKU for the App Service Plan
$appServicePlan.Sku.Name = $sku
$appServicePlan | Set-AzAppServicePlan
```

Comment: This way is intuitive and easy to configure. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

For anyone coming here in utter despair as I did, here is a little more context. I tried to upgrade an AppServicePlan from P1v2 to P2v2. However, this translates to:

`Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name $appServicePlanName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Tier "PremiumV2"  -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Medium"`

Note that `-Tier` points to the Tier **familiy** and the `-WorkerSize` points to the size (in the Portal or az cli this is P1, P2, P3 but in AzPowershell this is small/medium/large).

P1v2 = `-WorkerSize "Small"` and P3v2 = `-WorkerSize "Large"`

You can't make this stuff up...

Comment: Thanks my savior <3

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'AppServicePlanAuto' -ResourceGroupName 'Medium' -Tier Free -WorkerSize Small
Write-Output $plan.Sku.Size
```