# Upgrade Azure App Service with Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

I am trying to upgrade an app service plan(ASP) to the specific premium tier `P2V3` from `S1`.

I am using the following piece of code:

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "<RG Group Name>" -Name "<App service Name>" -Tier "PremiumV3" -WorkerSize Medium | Out-null;
```

It is upgrading from `S1` to `P1`. Any clue on this? would greatly appreciate it. couldn't find similar post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to upgrade an azure app service plan using powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059741/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-an-azure-app-service-plan-using-powershell)

Comment: Actually I am able to upgrade to  `P2V2` using `-Tier "PremiumV2" -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Medium"` and `P3V2` using ``-Tier "PremiumV2" -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "large"` But I want to upgrade to P2V3

Comment: and this falls in `Premium v3` and I tried with `-Tier "PremiumV3" -NumberofWorkers 1 -WorkerSize "Medium"`

Comment: **Note**: `Some App Service plans can't scale up to the PremiumV3 tier if the underlying App Service deployment doesn’t support PremiumV3.`  Refer: [Scale up from an unsupported resource group and region combination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#unsupported)

Comment: As per this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#azure-powershell you should be able to upgrade to P2V3. Make sure that underlying App Service deployment support PremiumV3 as per the above comment.

Comment: It is supported, I am able to do it from Azure Portal. I am trying to automate it through PowerShell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment to upgrade my App service plan fromP2V3 from S1.

- Created an app service plan with S1 Plan.
  [image]

To upgrade our Azure appservice plan to premium tier P2V3 from S1 we need to run the below cmd

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName "nameofrg" -Name "Ajupgrade" -Tier "PremiumV3" -WorkerSize "Medium"
```

Here is output screenshot for reference:
[image]
[image]

For more information please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azappserviceplan?view=azps-7.0.0) & [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059741/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-an-azure-app-service-plan-using-powershell?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**UPDATE:**

Note:**Please make sure that Powershell version is updated**

Comment: Is this dependent on the PowerShell version ?

Comment: In which version you are running ..?  I am running on PS VERSION 7.2.0 on Cloud Shell itself

Comment: Also please refer this and check whether its manually available or not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier#scale-up-an-existing-app-to-premiumv3-tier

Comment: The issue was with my PowerShell version, after upgradation it worked.