# Scaling an app service plan with Set-AzAppServicePlan

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-app-service-plans

I have a service plan currently on the `Premium v3 P1V3` tier. I'm trying to scale it to the `Premium v3 P0V3` tier overnight via a runbook with PowerShell to save some money. I can't see anywhere in the documentation how the list of available SKUs translates to a Tier and WorkerSize. I'd have thought that It would go as follows:

- P0V3 - Tier=Premium V3, WorkerSize=Small
- P1V3 - Tier=Premium V3, WorkerSize=Medium
- P2V3 - Tier=Premium V3, WorkerSize=Large
- P3V3 - Tier=Premium V3, WorkerSize=Extra Large

Yet when I run:

```
Set-AzAppServicePlan -Name 'my-uks-plan' -ResourceGroupName 'my-rg' -Tier "Premium V3" -WorkerSize Small
```

I end up on P1V3. There's some documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/set-azappserviceplan?view=azps-10.4.1 which doesn't even list the available values for the WorkerSize argument. I pieced together the sall/medium/large values from a different SO post.

The JSON resource view in the overview panel lists all of the worker size/counts as "6" and makes no mention of small. I tried specifying the WorkerSize as Small, and got an error about the value not being found in the dictionary.

There's also a terrifying list of SKUs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-configure-premium-tier (below) which doesn't seem to fit with the s/m/l model at all.

[image: Death by a thousand SKUs]

Is there a list of these mappings somewhere or a more intuitive way to change the SKU via PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any official documentation on the "worker size" but I was able to find the size mapping explained on several forums.

- P1 = Small
- P2 = Medium
- P3 = Large

References:

[App Service Plan Scaling Azure PowerShell](https://www.isjw.uk/post/azure/azure-powershell-app-service-plan-scale/)

[App Service Worker Size -> pricing tiers translation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/257485/app-service-worker-size-)-pricing-tiers-translatio)

Comment: That's what I'd have though. Kind of makes sense that P1 = Small, but then what's P0? Extra Small?

Comment: I suspect it's "ExtraSmall" based on how some of the VMs are named, but that's a guess.  I haven't been able to find the value specified anywhere.

Comment: A little more information on it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63059741/is-there-a-way-to-upgrade-an-azure-app-service-plan-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in the post at **https://stackoverflow.com/a/76107563/30512**

You can specify the SKU rather than guessing worker sizes.